# Centos - logrotate won't rotate

Tags: centos, logrotate

I have /etc/logrotate.d/httpd settled as :

```
/var/log/httpd/* {
    rotate 3
    size 10k
    missingok
    notifempty
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
       service httpd restart
    endscript
}
```

but in my /var/log/httpd I have:

```
[root@localhost httpd]# ls -al
totale 200
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root  4096 30 ott 17:13 .
drwxr-xr-x 12 root root  4096 30 ott 17:11 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root     0 30 ott 17:13 access_log
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   329 30 ott 17:13 error_log
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 86427 30 ott 17:20 ssl_access_log
-rw-r--r--  1 root root     0 30 ott 17:13 ssl_error_log
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 88443 30 ott 17:20 ssl_request_log
[root@localhost httpd]#
```

so for a check, I do logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.d/http and I get:

```
[root@localhost httpd]# logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.d/httpd
Interruzione di httpd:                                     [  OK  ]
Avvio di httpd: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using localhost.localdomain for ServerName
                                                           [  OK  ]
```

and I obtain correctly in my /var/log/httpd:

```
[root@localhost httpd]# ls -al
totale 340
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root   4096 30 ott 17:21 .
drwxr-xr-x 12 root root   4096 30 ott 17:11 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root      0 30 ott 17:13 access_log
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    329 30 ott 17:21 error_log
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    395 30 ott 17:21 error_log.1
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  48809 30 ott 17:26 ssl_access_log
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 103234 30 ott 17:21 ssl_access_log.1
-rw-r--r--  1 root root      0 30 ott 17:13 ssl_error_log
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  49541 30 ott 17:26 ssl_request_log
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 105502 30 ott 17:21 ssl_request_log.1
[root@localhost httpd]#
```

but looks like logrotate doesn't fire automatically every 10k size of files is reached even since the manual says "size" parameter should make logrotating once size is reached also before hourly/daily/...

Any clue?

Thanks to all ! 
Cheers
Luigi

Comment: Right, it fires when crontab tells it to fire, then it compares the sizes / age.  This isnt something that triggers the moment it hits 10k.

Comment: yoonix , so the only way to "contain" possible increasing of logs is to set hourly cron?...

Comment: I guess it would work but 10k is ridiculously small.